# Android: Element Activity is now allowed here

Tags: android

In the code below Android Studio shows me

"Element activity is now allowed here"

when I hover over **activity** tag, and the app doesn't launch the activity which is the default one, I tried clean project, rebuild project then restarted Android Studio, I tried invalidate cashes / restart, and the problem still exist, how to fix this?

```
    <activit
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activit>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blabla.testapp1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat? post it

Comment: Make sure the `<activity>` element is a child of the `<application>` element in your manifest. Also check your spelling, your posted code has `<activit>` instead of `<activity>`

Comment: @keno Great eye, thank you, the missed "y" was the reason of the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest i see you wrote `activit` instead of `activity`. Make it okey

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```